# What is the difference between formControlName and FormControl?

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular2-forms, form-control, angular2-formbuilder

I'm using `ReactiveFormsModule` of Angular2 to create a component that contains a form. Here is my code:

**foo.component.ts**:

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
        'fullname': ['', Validators.required],
        'gender': []
    });
}
```

**foo.component.html** (with `[formControl]`):

```
<div class="fields">
    <div class="field">
        <label>Fullname*</label>
        <input type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls.fullname"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="inline fields">
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" checked="" tabindex="0" class="hidden" [formControl]="myForm.controls.gender">
            <label>Male</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" tabindex="0" class="hidden" [formControl]="myForm.controls.gender">
            <label>Female</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**foo.component.html** (with `formControlName`):

```
<div class="fields">
    <div class="field">
        <label>Fullname*</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="fullname"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="inline fields">
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" checked="" tabindex="0" class="hidden" formControlName="gender">
            <label>Male</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" tabindex="0" class="hidden" formControlName="gender">
            <label>Female</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both ways work. But i cannot figure out what is the difference between using `[formControl]` and `formControlName`.

Comment: I'd say that the main reason for using formControlName over formControl is when you don't want to maintain individual FormControl instances in the component.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

I believe you missed an important point: `[formGroup]` directive in the second example. `formControlName` is used together with `[formGroup]` to save your form multiple dot navigations. For example:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls.firstName"/>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls.lastName"/>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls.email"/>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls.title"/>
</div>
```

Is equivalent to:

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstName"/>
  <input type="text" formControlName="lastName"/>
  <input type="text" formControlName="email"/>
  <input type="text" formControlName="title"/>
</div>
```

Now imagine nested `FormGroups` :)

Comment: using [formControl]="form.get('Registration.Attributes.aboutme')" caused issues.. but works fine with formControlName="firstNRegistration.Attributes.aboutmeame"

Comment: I past two weeks stuck at one activity on my work and your answer save me. Thank you guy!

Comment: I wonder whether formControlName is still a good approach in 2023. With typed forms we now have help from the compiler. If you use [formControl] you get an error if you reference a control that doesn't exist. If you use formControlName this error happens at runtime. Nesting can be achieved by defining an alias like this: `*ngIf="myForm.controls.nested as nested"`. And using form validation you usually have to reference the control in some expression anyways.

Answer (score 29):

`[formControl]` assigns a reference to the `FormControl` instance you created to the `FormControlDirective`.

`formControlName` assigns a string for the forms module to look up the control by name.

If you create variables for the controls, you also don't need the `.` as mentioned by Harry, but I'd also suggest to use `[formGroup]` instead because with more complicated forms this can become messy.

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.fullName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.gender = new FormControl('');
    this.myForm = fb.group({
        'fullname': this.fullName,
        'gender': this.gender
    });
}
```

Comment: when I add this.fullName = new FormControl('', Validators.required); I got an error like you cannot assign because it's read-only property or constant, but here I am taken as a variable.So please help

Comment: Please post the **exact** error message. It's probably even better to create a new question containing your code that allows to reproduce

Answer (score 11):

There is a 3rd equivalency to the two provided in the accepted answer, which is this (not recommended):

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input type="text" [formControl]="firstName"/>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="lastName"/>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="email"/>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="title"/>
</div>
```

Notice that we are still using the [formGroup] directive.

However, for this template to compile without error, then your component needs to declare the controls as AbstractControls and not FormControls:

myComponent.ts

```
firstName: AbstractControl
lastName: AbstractControl
email: AbstractControl
title: AbstractControl
```

However, please note that declaring AbstractControls is [not recommended](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl), so if you get the error `Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute` then it is probable you have mixed the styles or have declared your controls as AbstractControls.

Comment: how can i handle if the input elent is another component. how do I bind the fomrcontrol withe the component

Comment: You cannot - even if there IS a way, you should not. The element should be bound to the control defined IN THAT COMPONENT. If you want to pass data to another component then use a service (or if it is parent component then event emitter). Google how to pass data between components

Comment: can you please look at this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100248/how-do-i-bind-output-values-of-another-component-to-a-form-control-in-my-compone

Answer (score 5):

From the Angular docs (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms):

**Component**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
  });
}
```

---

**Template**

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">

  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </label>

  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
  </label>

</form>
```

> Note that just as the `FormGroup` contains a group of controls, the
>   profileForm `FormGroup` is bound to the form element with the `FormGroup`
>   directive, creating a communication layer between the model and the
>   form containing the inputs. The `formControlName` input provided by the
>   `FormControlName` directive binds each individual input to the form
>   control defined in the `FormGroup`

Answer (score 0):

with `[formControl]` you can use Reactive programming advantages because `FormControl` has a property named `valueChanges` (I know this one right now, maybe there is more than that) which returns an `Observable` which you can subscribe and use it. (for example, it is very useful in register scenarios which you want to check input email to be not repeated as soon as user change the value)

Comment: Yes. But you still use formControlName in the template, even when using the model in your answer. Just assign the formControlName=“someFormControlName” to a FormControl in the component.ts file like someFormControlName: FormControl;