# TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'abc@gmail.com' at setUpControl

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I face issue in `formGroup`. First Based on URL I take some value and call to API for retrieve particular user-data for pre-field text.

register.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 ">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input [formControl]="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email Address" [readonly]="isReadOnly">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

register.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, AbstractControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { EmailValidator, EqualPasswordsValidator } from '../../theme/validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'register',
  templateUrl: './register.html',
})
export class Register {
  public form: FormGroup;
  public email: AbstractControl;
  public username: string;

  constructor(private registerService: RegisterService, fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
      .... etc..
    });

    this.email = this.form.controls['email'];

    this.registerService.getUser({ userId: "asdasd2123da2das" }).subscribe(posts => {
      if (posts) {
          var userObj = posts.json();
          console.log("userObj : ", userObj.data);
          if (userObj.data && userObj.data[0].email) {
            this.email = this.username = userObj.data[0].email;  // ouput : abc@gmail.com
            this.isReadOnly = true;
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/register');
          } else {
            alert("You are Not Autorize to access this Page");
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          }
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Error Details :

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'abc@gmail.com'
    at setUpControl (http://localhost:3004/vendor.dll.js:9739:23)
    at FormControlDirective.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:3004/vendor.dll.js:44196:89)
    at Wrapper_FormControlDirective.ngDoCheck (/ReactiveFormsModule/FormControlDirective/wrapper.ngfactory.js:50:18)
```

Comment: Not having my service declared in the module's providers caused this same error.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 ">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input formControlName="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email Address" [readonly]="isReadOnly">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

please try like this change `[formControl]` to `formControlName`.

And to set the output to the input field please do the following, point the line `this.form.patchValue`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, AbstractControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { EmailValidator, EqualPasswordsValidator } from '../../theme/validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'register',
  templateUrl: './register.html',
})
export class Register {
  public form: FormGroup;
  public email: AbstractControl;
  public username: string;

  constructor(private registerService: RegisterService, fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
      .... etc..
    });

    this.email = this.form.controls['email'];

    this.registerService.getUser({ userId: "asdasd2123da2das" }).subscribe(posts => {
      if (posts) {
          var userObj = posts.json();
          console.log("userObj : ", userObj.data);
          if (userObj.data && userObj.data[0].email) {
            this.email = this.username = userObj.data[0].email;  // ouput : abc@gmail.com
            this.form.patchValue({
                email : this.email
             });

            this.isReadOnly = true;
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/register');
          } else {
            alert("You are Not Autorize to access this Page");
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @higunjan please refer the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171914/what-is-the-difference-between-formcontrolname-and-formcontrol

Comment: Yes agree but `this.email = this.username = userObj.data[0].email` I got value but it didn't set in email fields.

Comment: actually you want to set the output to the input field. right?

Comment: Yes Right  `<input formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email Address" [readonly]="isReadOnly">`

Can I use `[(ngModel)] = "email" . It's work but is their any side effect

Comment: it is better to not use ngModel along with formControlName because one is template driven and other is model driven

Comment: Please suggest me better way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142595/discussion-between-sainu-and-higunjan).

Comment: It fixed my issue

Comment: What the diddly! [cit.] I copied a snippet and I removed the `[]` from `formControl` but I didn't realise it should become `formControlName`. Thanks.

Comment: @sainu Please help me to understand why we are getting the error, because @higunjan has already binding the `form` in 1st line so he can use [formControl]="anyControlName". So why we need to change it to formControlName ? I am attaching one link of angular doc (Line no 3 in input-error-state-matcher-example.html) [https://stackblitz.com/angular/enjmxbpeakq?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts](https://stackblitz.com/angular/enjmxbpeakq?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts) . I hope you/anyone will help me to understand.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar can you please see the answer of this question > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171914/what-is-the-difference-between-formcontrolname-and-formcontrol

Comment: simply `formControlName` is used together with `[formGroup]`

Answer (score 14):

I missed the square brackets in formGroup in markup as below

```
<form formGroup="form">
</form>
```

and it throws similar error as

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'form'

Once the square brackets added in formGroup (see below), the error disappears

```
<form [formGroup]="form">....</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

For complete information about each kind of form, see Reactive Forms and Template-driven Forms from the https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview website. you are missing actual syntax for Grouping form controls and Registering the control in the template.both are valid in different case

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="name">
<input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
```