# Need some advice on [formGroup] formGroupName ,[formControl] formControlName

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am looking at the existing answer for question
[What is the difference between formControlName and FormControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171914/what-is-the-difference-between-formcontrolname-and-formcontrol)

and still struggle to fully understand when to use [formControl] over formControlName.

Am I correct to conclude [ based on @Paul Samsotha  comment ] that when I create a control using FormBuilder similar to the

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
        'fullname': ['', Validators.required],
        'gender': []
    });
}
```

Then I should use something like

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="fullname">
  </label>

  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="gender">
  </label>

</form>
```

and if I want to declare my form like the following (based on @Günter Zöchbauer ansewer):

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
        'fullname': new FormControl('');
        'gender': new FormControl('')
    });
}
```

use the following syntax:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" [formControl]="fullname">
  </label>

  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" [formControl]="gender">
  </label>

</form>
```

Is above correct? Also the same thing for [formGroup] and formGroupName: When would you use formGroupName over [formGroup]? *I could not come up with an example for this one*. Can you explain why one might use one over the other or what the recommended practice is (if any)?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you use [formControl] or [formControlName] when your form is dynamic, when you have a fixed form you just use formControlName.

That happens because the [] structure in angular is one way binding, so it keeps watching for the value of any property you have in your component.

- [formControl]="propertyInComponent"
- [formControlName]="propertyInComponent"
- formControlName="nameGivenByYou"

Comment: We can also use `[formControlName]` for dynamic forms. FormControl is used for standalone controls