# how to select options when a edit mode using Material Design

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using the dropdown to multiple select roles. When click an edit button, I want to `2 roles` to be checked out of `3 roles`. because the user has two roles `admin, dashboards` out of `admin, dashboards, user`.

I will check the roles from the server and the list of roles and if the role names are the same I will make the `selected = true`. So, I can only select options that `selected is true`. 
 How do I realize that? This code is based on `Angular 8`.

**typescript**

```
this.user.roles = roles;
```

**role Model**

```
    id: number;
    name: string; 
    selected :boolean;
```

**html**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
        <mat-select placeholder="Role"
                    formControlName="roles"
                    multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="
                    let role of roles$ | async " [value]="role">
                {{ role.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-error *ngIf="isControlHasError('roles','required')">
            <strong>{{ 'AUTH.VALIDATION.REQUIRED_FIELD' | translate }}</strong>
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [(ngModel)]="role" instead of value in mat option

Answer (score 1):

To make the two way binding on the preselected/default value use `[formControl]`

```
<mat-select placeholder="Role" [formControl]="selectedRole" multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles$ | async " [value]="role.id">
    {{ role.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In the .component.ts your code should look something like this

```
selectedRole= new FormControl();
ngOnInit(){
  getUserRole()
}

getUserRole(){
...
this.selectedRole.setValue(role.id)  // role = {id:3,name:'user'}
}
```

Comment: This will give me two options. What I want to do is choosing 2 options out of three.

Comment: `selectedRole` should have the `[value]` field of `<mat-option>`

Comment: please check the updated answer also you need to do is to make the  `[value]` field not an **object**

Comment: other form controls made using what exactly? also using the example I've shared you're not using any `formControlName` property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171914/what-is-the-difference-between-formcontrolname-and-formcontrol
I want to keep using formControlName instead of formControl. Can I select two roles? instead of one?

Comment: yes, you can just make sure to populate the role property like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172083/4822545)